# How to change iframe pages without the parent page changing with external links using CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm working on a webpage where I need to be able to click on buttons that change iframes with in a parent page. I thought this would be a simple task but no matter what I do, the button keeps opening a new window rather than opening the page inside the iframe. The page looks perfect and the iframe loads up but when I click the button in the parent window to change the page it opens in a new tab. Here is the complete code I'm using (minus the changed webpage names) if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong please.

```
<head>
<style>
  body
  {
    background-image:url(bg4.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top;
    background-size:100%;
  }
  p.pos_fixed
  {
    position:fixed;
    top:98px;
    right:298px;
  }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Stupid webpage that dont work</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="pos_fixed">
    <iframe id="MSL" src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="975" height="800">
    </iframe>
    <center>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="MSL">
      <img src="MSL.jpg" alt="MSL" width="42" height="42"></a>
    </center>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your link to target the iframe, you must add the "name" attribute to such frame, nothing to do with "id"

```
<iframe id="MSL" name="MSL" src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="975" height="800">
</iframe>
```

Also, your DOM structure is very bad, you should not nest iFrames inside paragraphs. In short, the target attribute in anchor elements need to match the name attribute in the iFrame unless it is a reserved one such as "_blank", "_self", "_parent", or "_top".

Comment: I did name="MSL" didnt work I also tried name and id both at same time; didnt work

Comment: It should work as long as you don't use Google or Yahoo as the test pages, those return a header that does not allow iFrames to load them. So try using cnn.com and bbc.co.uk as those do allow, but adding the name attribute to the iframe does work.

Comment: See this fiddle, and see it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2JjVz/ (scroll to bottom for the button)

Comment: Got it! Its working now, I did try it before with the name= but I did it Name="/" id="/" Not sure if that was the deal where ID had to come 1st or if it was because I was using google as a test page but its working now! Thanks a lot you saved me :)